# How change or reset AttributedString's atribute?

Tags: java, awt

As there are no methods for changing or resetting attributes of `AttributedString` according to documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/AttributedString.html

How one can do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not mentioned in docs but it is possible to reassign attribute of `AttributedString` just by another addition of the same attribute:

```
AttributedString attributedString = new AttributedString("TEST TEXT");

attributedString.addAttribute(TextAttribute.BACKGROUND, Color.BLACK);//Initial assign
attributedString.addAttribute(TextAttribute.BACKGROUND, Color.GREEN);//Reassign
attributedString.addAttribute(TextAttribute.BACKGROUND, null);//Reset
```